# SQL - Grouping data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm at a bit of a loss on a query I'm writing when it comes to finally grouping the data.  Basically, I have designed the query and am now getting all of the data I want to see, but now I need to group the results by manifest number (man_no column).  Basically, I would be happy if the results only show the first instance of a unique manifest number, since the subsequent instances are actually the same data anyway.

Any advice?  As you can see from the data, the records are actually the same data but appear reversed in the "consignments" column results... I've probably just written the query poorly?

QUERY:

```
    SELECT landing_jobs.man_no, ltrim(rtrim(brun.veh_code)) as Run_Vehicle,
    ltrim(rtrim(landing_jobs.col_zone)) + ' - ' + ltrim(rtrim(landing_jobs.del_zone))         as coldel,
    CASE
    WHEN con2.long_no <> ' ' and landing_jh.est_time<=job_history2.est_time and         jmaster.col_state='SA' THEN dateadd(ss,1800,job_history2.est_time)
    WHEN (con2.long_no <> ' ' and landing_jh.est_time>job_history2.est_time and jmaster.col_state='SA') OR (con2.long_no IS null and jmaster.col_state='SA') then dateadd(ss,1800,Landing_JH.est_time)
    WHEN con2.long_no <> ' ' and landing_jh.est_time<=job_history2.est_time and jmaster.col_state='WA' THEN dateadd(ss,7200,job_history2.est_time)
    WHEN (con2.long_no <> ' ' and landing_jh.est_time>job_history2.est_time and jmaster.col_state='WA') OR (con2.long_no IS null and jmaster.col_state='WA') then dateadd(ss,7200,Landing_JH.est_time)
    WHEN con2.long_no <> ' ' and landing_jh.est_time<=job_history2.est_time and jmaster.col_state='QLD' THEN dateadd(ss,0,job_history2.est_time)
    WHEN (con2.long_no <> ' ' and landing_jh.est_time>job_history2.est_time and jmaster.col_state='QLD') OR (con2.long_no IS null and jmaster.col_state='QLD') then dateadd(ss,0,Landing_JH.est_time)
    ELSE landing_jh.est_time
    END AS dep_mel_time,

    CASE 
    WHEN con2.del_code<>' ' and con2.del_code<>landing_jobs.del_code then         LTRIM(rtrim(landing_jobs.del_code)) + ' / ' + LTRIM(rtrim(con2.del_code)) 
    ELSE ltrim(rtrim(landing_jobs.del_code))
    END AS deliveries,

    CASE
    WHEN con3.long_no<>' ' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(landing_jobs.long_no)) + '-' +         LTRIM(rtrim(landing_jobs.cus_code)) + ' and ' + LTRIM(rtrim(con2.long_no)) + '-' + LTRIM(rtrim(con2.cus_code)) + ' and ' + LTRIM(rtrim(con3.long_no)) + '-' + LTRIM(rtrim(con3.cus_code))
    WHEN con2.long_no<>' ' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(landing_jobs.long_no)) + '-' + LTRIM(rtrim(landing_jobs.cus_code)) + ' and ' + LTRIM(rtrim(con2.long_no)) + '-' + LTRIM(rtrim(con2.cus_code))
    ELSE LTRIM(rtrim(landing_jobs.long_no)) + '-' + ltrim(rtrim(Landing_Jobs.cus_code))
    END AS consignments,

    ltrim(rtrim(landing_jobs.trl_code1)) as con1trl1,
    ltrim(rtrim(landing_jobs.trl_code2)) as con1trl2,
    ltrim(rtrim(con2.trl_code1)) as con2trl1,
    ltrim(rtrim(con2.trl_code2)) as con2trl2,
    ltrim(rtrim(driver2.name))

    FROM landing_jobs left outer join landing_runs brun on landing_jobs.man_no=brun.job_no left outer join landing_driver driver2 on brun.drv_code=driver2.code left outer join landing_equipment on landing_equipment.code=brun.veh_code left outer join landing_driver on landing_driver.code=brun.drv_code left outer join landing_JH on landing_jobs.job_no=landing_JH.job_no and landing_JH.job_status='C' left outer join landing_jobs con2 on landing_jobs.man_no=con2.man_no and landing_jobs.job_no<>con2.job_no left outer join landing_JH job_history2 on job_history2.job_no=con2.job_no and job_history2.job_no<>landing_JH.job_no and job_history2.job_status='C' left outer join landing_jobs con3 on landing_jobs.man_no=con3.man_no and landing_jobs.job_no<>con3.job_no and con3.job_no<>con2.job_no LEFT join landing_jobs jmaster on landing_jobs.mas_no=jmaster.job_no
    WHERE landing_jobs.type='JL' and brun.work_code<>'LOCAL' and brun.veh_code<>'SC' and brun.veh_code<>' ' AND landing_jobs.col_zone<>landing_jobs.del_zone AND jmaster.srv_code<>'B/T' and landing_jobs.leg_item=1
    AND landing_jh.est_time >= '2013-07-01'


    order by dep_mel_time
```

RETURNS:

```
 man_no     Run_Vehicle     coldel     dep_mel_time     deliveries        consignments                        con1trl1     con1trl2     con2trl1     con2trl2     Driver
 349802     091V            ADE - WAGG 7/05/2014 18:00  WAGGA             349835JL#1-COPE and 349832JL#1-BFL     445       2541                                   EY Peter
 349802     091V            ADE - WAGG 7/05/2014 18:00  WAGGA             349832JL#1-BFL and 349835JL#1-COPE     2541                   445                       EY Peter
 349792     010V            ADE - MEL  7/05/2014 18:00  COPEMEL           349808JL#1-BFL and 349806JL#1-COPE     2005                   430                       THIELE Laura
 349792     010V            ADE - MEL  7/05/2014 18:00  COPEMEL           349806JL#1-COPE and 349808JL#1-BFL     430       2005                                   THIELE Laura
 349799     117V            ADE - MEL  7/05/2014 18:00  BFLMEL / POLYDAN  349825JL#1-BFL and 349823JL#1-POLYAIRE 2611                   5580                      DESTRO Bill
 349799     117V            ADE - MEL  7/05/2014 18:00  POLYDAN / BFLMEL  349823JL#1-POLYAIRE and 349825JL#1-BFL 5580      2611                                   DESTRO Bill
 349516     259             MEL - SYD  7/05/2014 19:00  CAMSYD            349455JL#1-CAMERON                     2590      688          NULL        NULL          WAIN Sarah
 349794     113V            ADE - NHIL 7/05/2014 19:00  NHILL             349820JL#1-WA FR                       2608      643          NULL        NULL          STEPNELL William
 349766     047K            SYD - MEL  7/05/2014 19:00  COSRIN            349686JL#1-COSTCO                      CC2622    CC5504       NULL        NULL          WINTERTON Mike
 349753     039K            SYD - MEL  7/05/2014 19:00  WAFGMELB          349661JL#1-WA FR                       2619      716          NULL        NULL          SIDHU Marpreet
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the results you would like to see.  Grouping should mean that you are trying to select an aggregate - e.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG`, or `COUNT`.  It's not clear from your current results and your problem description what results you would like to see instead, what you specifically want to aggregate per `man_no`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with `row_number()`.  I would suggest:

```
with cte as (<your query here (without the `order by`)>)
select t.*
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by man_no order by dep_mel_time desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

As a note, the records for a given `man_no` do not look like duplicates to me.  I see many differences in the columns.